# How to combine integer into a list

Tags: python

I was doing a problem from Codecademy which is:

1. Create a function named double_index. Two parameters: a list named lst and a single number named index.
2. The function returns a new list where all elements are the same as in lst except for the element at index. The element at index should be **double the value of the element at index of the original lst.**
3. If index is not a valid index, the function should return the original list.

My code is:

```
def double_index(lst, index):
   if index <= len(lst) and index >0:
      double_value = lst[index]*2
      new_lst = lst[:index] + list(double_value) + lst[index+1:]
      return new_lst
   else:
      return lst
```

However, when I run the code, the error occurs at line 4 where "int is not iterable" because of double_value.

Did I use the list() function wrong? Or is there some conceptual error here?

Comment: You can just wrap double_value in [ ] to  form a list

Answer (score 0):

`list` expects an iterable object, so it cannot be used with a number.

When you need a single-item list, just use `[value]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just switch the value of the specified element by getting into it by it's index:

```
if index <= len(lst) and index >0:
      lst[index] *= 2
      return lst
else:
      return lst
```